# For which recursive functions (or infinite expressions) can substitution be used for a solution?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion, golden-ratio

I have a question about recursive functions and their convergence as sequences.

We know that the golden ratio can be represented by:
$$
\phi= 1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{...}}}
$$
Rewriting the above infinite expression as a recursive function gives us:
$$
\phi(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}
$$
$\lim_{p \to \infty} \phi^p(x)$ converges to the golden ratio for $x \in \mathbb{R}, x\neq0,\Phi$ (the golden ratio conjugate). The solution for this convergence can be found when substituting $\phi(x)$ in for $x$ if you assume $\lim_{p \to \infty} \phi^p(x)=\phi^{p-1}(x)$. My question is: for which recursive functions (as a sequence) can you assume that for in order to solve for convergence? Also, how will you know how many solutions there are for any of these functions? Here's a few examples I've found/wondered about:
$$
\phi(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}, \lim_{p \to \infty} \phi^p(x)=1.618... \text{ (unless $x=0,\Phi$), two convergences ($\phi$ and $\Phi$), for } x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{2}, \lim_{p \to \infty} f^p(x)=0, \text{one convergence, for } x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
d(x)=x-1+0^{x-1}, \lim_{p \to \infty} d^p(x)=1, \text{one convergence, for } x \in \mathbb{N} \text{ (a strange function, but I'm still curious)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were able to see that your recursion was of the form $x_{n+1} = \phi(x_n)$. Therefore, if you assume that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence, it must converge to a fixed point of $\phi$, .i.e. a solution of the equation
$x = \phi(x)$. In your example, $x = \phi(x) \Leftrightarrow  x = \frac 12 (1\pm \sqrt{5})$, where one of the solutions can be discarded based on the signal of the terms.

This "method" can be used whenever you can assure that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence. The fixed point theorem gives nice sufficient conditions for convergence, just based on the behavior of $\phi(x)$ and $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you, time to turn my attention to the fixed point theorem. By any chance, do you have any thoughts about the other two functions as well?

Comment: Regarding $f(x)$, any recursive sequence of the form $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ converges to zero, since you can check that $x_{n} = \frac{x_0}{2^n}$. In fact, zero is the only solution of the equation $x = \frac x2$. I don't quite understand your last example.

Comment: If you assume $0^0=1$ (you could always use a simple piecewise instead, but I'm using $0^0$ for ease and readability), then would using substitution be used for $d(x)=x-1+0^{x-1}$? If it is, how does that function (which converges to 1 for $x\in\mathbb{N}$) compare to $c(x)=x+1-0^{x-1}$, which only converges to 1 for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ if $x=1$? Sorry if that's a tad confusing...

Comment: Do you mean that 
$$d(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x = 1\\ x-1, & x \ne 1\end{cases}?$$

If that is the case, the convergence depends entirely on $x_0$. If $x_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, the sequence  will converge to $1$. For other values of $x_0$ the sequence diverges (or converges to $-\infty$, if you prefer).

Comment: Yes, I do mean that, thank you so much.